# .Net Progressbar before show form

Tags: .net, progress-bar

I have a problem because my form "form1" loads during 40 secs ... so I want to create a progress bar (marquee style) before to show the form loaded.

Do yo have some special source to learn that?

Comment: That progressbar won't animate while your form is loading.  Focus on *why* your form is so slow to load, you must be doing something nontrivial in the constructor or Load event.  Put that code in a BackgroundWorker instead.  Your progressbar is now simple to implement, hide it in the RunworkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: If you're using VB.Net then simply create a "splash" form with the Marquee ProgressBar on it and set that as the Splash Form in Project --> Properties.  It will display as long as your "Startup Object" Form is loading.

Answer (score 1):

you'd need to load another form first that only contains a progress bar and launch your "true" application after that. It's up to you to decide how you want your "true" application window to report loading progress back to your loading window. You could just use a "dumb" progress bar to show something is happening if that's acceptable to your users.